# Code coverage for Scala integration tests with SCCT

Tags: scala, integration-testing, sbt, code-coverage, scct

I'm running integration tests in Scala - these are found in the `src/it/scala` directory, and I've added the following to my build.sbt:

```
seq(Defaults.itSettings: _*)
```

However, when I run SCCT to calculate code coverage, the integration tests are not run.  How can I make them be run?

Comment: Looking at [ScctPlugin](https://github.com/mtkopone/sbt-scct/blob/f92fc39a5f243591504dd0e6d6a736239f909ad4/src/main/scala/ScctPlugin.scala) `scct:test` runs test in a custom configuration called `ScctTest`, but it's missing the support for the integration tests. You'd need to create something like `ScctIntegrationTest` and set up all the settings for it. Probably better off asking the authors to add the feature to sbt-scct.

Comment: SCCT is obsolete. https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage is what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

I am using scct 0.3-SNAPSHOT / sbt 0.13

for mergin test + it:test try the following setting:

```
ScctPlugin.instrumentSettings ++ Defaults.itSettings ++ Seq(
  resourceDirectory in ScctPlugin.ScctTest <<= (resourceDirectory in Test),
  sources in ScctPlugin.ScctTest ++= (sources in IntegrationTest).value
)
```

this might get tricky if you have different resources